# Leaflet.js draw line along rivers between two points

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, leaflet, mapbox, node-request

I am looking to draw a line along a few rivers (they merge so the river name technically changes) with Leaflet.js. I am currently using a Mapbox custom map style to display the map but I'm at a loss of how to "draw" a line along these rivers, from one marker to another.

**EDIT**
Thanks to @ghybs who pointed me in the right direction (below).

I now have this code which works perfectly for getting the data. However. The problem is that the nodes are not "in order". I'd like the nodes to be in order with regards to the river, so that I can draw the line. Currently, because they are not sequential, the line is all over the place.

The code is utilising [Request](http://npmjs.org/package/reqest) to get the data, hence the calls are asynchronous. I think this is what's leading to the ordering issue.

```
var request = require("request");
var parseString = require("xml2js").parseString;
var fs = require("fs");

var results = [];

request("https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/5806846", function(error, response, body){
    // var body = fs.readFileSync("relation.xml");
    var total_requests = 0;
    var completed_requests = 0;
    parseString(body, function(err, result){
        var ways = result.osm.relation[0].member;
        console.log("Initial requests: " + ways.length);
        total_requests += ways.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < ways.length; i++) {
            var way = ways[i].$.ref;
            (function(way, i){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    request("https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/"+way, function(error, response, body){
                        completed_requests++;
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            console.log("https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/" + way + " failed");
                        }
                        else {
                            parseString(body, function(err, result){
                                var nodes = result.osm.way[0].nd;
                                console.log("Total requests " +  + nodes.length);
                                total_requests += nodes.length;
                                for (var i2 = 0; i2 < nodes.length; i2++){
                                    var node = nodes[i2].$.ref;
                                    (function(node, i){
                                        setTimeout(function(){
                                            request("https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/"+node, function(error, response, body){
                                                completed_requests++;
                                                if (error) {
                                                    console.log(error);
                                                    console.log("https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/" + node + " failed");
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    parseString(body, function(err, result){
                                                        var lat = result.osm.node[0].$.lat;
                                                        var long = result.osm.node[0].$.lon;
                                                        results.push([lat, long]);
                                                    });
                                                    console.log(total_requests + "/" + completed_requests);
                                                    if (completed_requests == total_requests){
                                                        console.log("Done");
                                                        console.log("Got " + results.length + " results");
                                                        fs.writeFile("little_ouse.json", JSON.stringify(results), function(err) {
                                                            if (err) {
                                                                return console.log(err);
                                                            }
                                                            console.log("The file was saved");
                                                        }); 
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }, i * 1000);
                                    })(node, i2);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }, i * 1000);
            })(way, i)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have the rivers paths coordinates and what to display them on top of the basemap? Do you want to manually redraw the rivers? Do you need to retrieve the rivers paths from somewhere else?

Comment: @ghybs I know where the rivers go and I would like to avoid manually redrawing them. Mapbox _knows_ where the rivers are, because I was able to change the colour for waterways, it's just how to extract that information so I can "draw" a line along them.

Comment: Are you trying to include more content (additional line) on your custom Mapbox map? Or do you want to add interactive line once the map is displayed through Leaflet?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to add it as an interactive line with Leaflet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would like to **extract** your rivers paths from the OSM database (which is what Mapbox studio uses to let you customize your basemap style).

On [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) main website, you have a big "Export" button at the top. You can use it to extract all the data contained in a given bounding box, including the coordinates of the paths for your rivers.

Then you can use other tools to convert to GeoJSON and keep only the data related to your rivers (e.g. http://geojson.io/).

Once you have your data as GeoJSON, you can easily display it on Leaflet using `L.geoJson(myGeoJSONdata).addTo(map)`

Comment: I had to take a slightly different approach because the exported dataset was so large - please could you take a look at the updated Q above and see what you think?